# Simplejson и ошибка

Tags: python-3.x, json

Я пишу скрипт на очистку и склейку своих json'ов, из-за ошибки я вынужден был перейти на simplejson, сам код:

```
import simplejson as json
...
a = json.load(users1.json, encoding='utf-8')
...
```

Ошибка:

```
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'users1' is not defined
```

Не знаю что делать, вроде делаю всё правильно, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Что такое `users1`?

Comment: Файл с данными которые я хочу вытащить и склеить с другими файлами

Comment: @Vorobuska приведите определение его в коде. Если вы имеете в виду "название файла", то используйте строку `"users1.json"`

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, я уже мозг сломал)